# Spring Data JPA - Get the values of a non-entity column of a custom native query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot/MVC.
I have a custom query using JpaRepository:

```
 public interface WorkOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<WorkOrder, Integer> {
 @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM workorder) Sub1 INNER JOIN (SELECT wo_number, GROUP_CONCAT(service_type SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'service_types' FROM service_type GROUP BY wo_number) Sub2 ON Sub1.wo_number=Sub2.wo_number WHERE fleet_company_id=?1 AND (order_status='On-Bidding' OR order_status='Draft')", nativeQuery = true)
 Collection<WorkOrder> findWorkOrdersByFleet(Long fleetCompanyID);
 }
```

It returns the following table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmTh6.jpg

As you can see it has service_types columns which is a result of Concat, it's not part of the entity class. My problem is how can I get the value of that column. Some said I can use a separate DTO to map the service_types column? Or I can use 'new' keyword? Maybe you have other worked on me. I also tried to make a transient column service_types but it didn't work.

This is my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="workorder")
public class WorkOrder {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="wo_number")
private Long woNumber;

@ManyToOne(optional=false, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "vehicle_id")
private Vehicle vehicle;

@ManyToOne(optional=false, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "fleet_company_id")
private FleetCompany fleetCompany;

@Column(name="order_title")
private String orderTitle;

@Column(name="order_date")
private String orderDate;

@Column(name="order_time")
private String orderTime;

@Column(name="order_status")
private String orderStatus;

@Column(name="ref_number")
private String refNumber;

@Column(name="proposals")
private int proposals;


//@Column(name="serviceTypes")
@Transient
private int serviceTypes;

public WorkOrder() {
    super();
}


public Long getWoNumber() {
    return woNumber;
}


public void setWoNumber(Long woNumber) {
    this.woNumber = woNumber;
}


public String getOrderTitle() {
    return orderTitle;
}


public void setOrderTitle(String orderTitle) {
    this.orderTitle = orderTitle;
}


public String getOrderDate() {
    return orderDate;
}


public void setOrderDate(String orderDate) {
    this.orderDate = orderDate;
}


public String getOrderTime() {
    return orderTime;
}


public void setOrderTime(String orderTime) {
    this.orderTime = orderTime;
}


public String getOrderStatus() {
    return orderStatus;
}


public void setOrderStatus(String orderStatus) {
    this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
}


public String getRefNumber() {
    return refNumber;
}


public void setRefNumber(String refNumber) {
    this.refNumber = refNumber;
}


public int getProposals() {
    return proposals;
}


public void setProposals(int proposals) {
    this.proposals = proposals;
}


public Vehicle getVehicle() {
    return vehicle;
}


public void setVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
    this.vehicle = vehicle;
}


public FleetCompany getFleetCompany() {
    return fleetCompany;
}


public void setFleetCompany(FleetCompany fleetCompany) {
    this.fleetCompany = fleetCompany;
}


public int getServiceTypes() {
    return serviceTypes;
}


public void setServiceTypes(int serviceTypes) {
    this.serviceTypes = serviceTypes;
}


}
```

Some people told me to make a DTO:

```
public class WorkOrderDTO extends WorkOrder {

private String service_types;

public WorkOrderDTO() {
    super();
}

public WorkOrderDTO(String service_types) {
    this.service_types = service_types;
}

public String getService_types() {
    return service_types;
}

public void setService_types(String service_types) {
    this.service_types = service_types;
}

}
```

and add make the repository replaced from WorkOrder to WorkOrderDTO.

```
 public interface WorkOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<WorkOrderDTO, Integer>
```

but when I do that I have autowiring problems.

Comment: Are you really going to ask the same question every 8 hours?

Comment: and when you take the advice of these "some" who said "use a DTO" what happened? and don't say "it didn't work", because that statement would be completely pointless without information as to WHAT happened.

Comment: @NeilStockton I edited my post to add what happened. I basically encountered an autowiring problem.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for pushing me to solve my own problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem, finally!!!
I used @SqlResultMapping

```
 SqlResultSetMapping(
    name="workorder",
    classes={
        @ConstructorResult(
            targetClass=WorkOrderDTO.class,
            columns={
                @ColumnResult(name="wo_number", type = Long.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="service_types", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="order_title", type = String.class)
            }
        )
    }
)
```

And I created a new POJO that is not an entity named WorkOrderDTO.

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
@Override
public Collection<WorkOrderDTO> getWork() {
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(
              "SELECT Sub1.wo_number, Sub2.service_types, Sub1.order_title FROM (SELECT * FROM workorder) Sub1 INNER JOIN (SELECT wo_number, GROUP_CONCAT(service_type SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'service_types' FROM service_type GROUP BY wo_number) Sub2 ON Sub1.wo_number=Sub2.wo_number WHERE fleet_company_id=4 AND (order_status='On-Bidding' OR order_status='Draft')", "workorder");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Collection<WorkOrderDTO> dto = query.getResultList();

    Iterable<WorkOrderDTO> itr = dto;
    return (Collection<WorkOrderDTO>)itr;
}
```

At last, the users who hated me for posting the same problem won't be annoyed anymore.